# Overlay of multiple colors in ImageJ

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I'm writing a little plugin for imageJ and I am drawing several regions as an overlay on the image.

I'm using this code:

```
ImagePlus imp = getImage();
Overlay ov = new Overlay();
for (int r=0; r<regions.length; r++)
    {
    ov.add(regions[r]);
    }
imp.setOverlay(ov);
```

Where `regions` is an array of Roi.

This works as intended and draws the regions in the (hurting to my eyes) standard ImageJ cyan used for overlays. I would like to draw *one* particular region in another colour, but I cannot seem to find a way to do it. I found that you can change the colour of the *whole* overlay, but I need two colours in the same overlay.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

nico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to set the drawing colours for each `Roi` object individually via its `setFillColor` and `setStrokeColor` methods.